# CMake and multiple Visual Studio installations using the same compiler version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

### Scenario

A colleague set up a system a while back. They installed Visual Studio 15 Comminity Edition, merely to test the build process.

At some later point, another colleague was assigned to use that machine. Unbeknownst to them, there was Visual Studio 15 still installed on this machine, but since we have commercial licenses they installed Visual Studio 15 Professional in addition to the alrready installed Community Edition.

### Behavior

It is of important note, that the Community Edition installation had the MFC toolset installed, while the Professional Edition installation had not.

Afterwards, the second colleague used our automated procedure to call CMake to first generate project files for Visual Studio, then used the standard command to execute the build pipeline:

`cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64" .`

This resulted in compilation errors, because the Professional Edition did not have the MFC toolset available and thus the build pipeline failed. Yet within the IDE compilation was successful. After a short while was discovered, that opening "Visual Studio" via Windows start menu resulted in opening the Community Edition rather than the Professional Edition. Since the MFC toolset was then availale, IDE compilation was successful.

### Question

Is the solution to this problem as obvious as it seems or does CMake have some way to determine which compiler to use?

Currently I have the following assumptions and would like to validate or refute them:

- Each of the Visual Studio versions came with their own compiler for which the respective installers are able to enable/disable additional toolsets.
- These two Visual Studio versions *do not share* the same comiler. (That they do not share toolsets does seem obvious)
- CMake has no additional settings to declare which of the compilers of these distinct Visual Studio installations is to be used to execute the build pipeline.
- The reason CMake utilized the Professional Edition compiler to execute the build pipeline is merely because the Professional version was installed second, likely overriding a path (registry entry?) CMake uses to find the compiler.

Is this assessment correct? Did something else happen here?

Comment: It is a good idea to manually setup toolchains for cmake instead of relying on obscure autodetection.

Comment: I suggest reinstalling the system, because I think this won't be the only problem with two installed VS 2015 versions

Comment: @RoQuOTriX what other problems would you expect in addition? I know multiple VS installations can coexist on one system, but have not had any experience handling two installations of the same version (even though editions vary in this case).

Comment: I got problems with using Qt-Addins on a system installed VS 2015 and VS 2017, but maybe I set up things wrong. I don't have any experience of that use-case either, but you know, it is windows and every program more, will make it more unstable, even then, when you installed the same big program twice. It is not a fact based opinion, more based on feelings

Comment: When executed with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64"`, CMake expects to be in the environment set with `vcvarsall.bat` script. By running the script corresponded to the specific Visual Studio installation you may control what CMake will do during the configuration.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That is what I have been looking for. Thank you.